# Php algorithm solution?

Tags: php, algorithm

In PHP

If you had an array of one million integers, how would you go to print each integer that contain the number seven(eg..7,17,67..) with out using a loop?

Comment: I assume this is your homework?

Comment: Loops have been introduced to avoid writing (copying) the same code multiple times. So, you have 2 options - either to use a loop (doesn't really matter if it is `for` or `foreach` loop or some function like `array_filter` or `array_walk` - in fact, they all are loops), or write the code for checking single integer one million times.

Comment: Without a loop? You don't. Mentioned array functions loop trough the array internally, so a loop does occur. If you want to avoid constructing the loop in PHP, then you use mentioned `array_filter`, `array_walk` or `array_map` functions.

Comment: @JohnBallinger this was actually a job interview question.

Comment: Are you going to outsource your job to SO as well? )

Comment: @raina77ow Am I not allowed to learn and evolve?

Comment: Of course you are. ) But would it hurt to make a bit of research and coding by yourself, and show us _your_ efforts? )

Comment: @raina77ow You are right, Ill keep that in mind for next time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this'll be it? )

```
$one_million_number_array = array(1, 1232, 347, 898, 777);
function echo_if_contains_seven($val) {
    if (strpos($val, '7') !== FALSE) { 
        echo $val, "\n"; 
    } 
}

array_walk($one_million_number_array, 'echo_if_contains_seven');
```

Comment: hey, strpos(), kinda confuses me, in the PHP documentation it says that it returns the position of the needle, so how come when i put seven to be as the first string, so position 0, it still prints seven ?

Comment: It's understandable that you're a bit confused. ) In PHP `strpos()` acts weird: it may, as you rightly said, return `0` when the needle is right at the top of the haystack, but it will return `FALSE` when the needle isn't found at all. That's why you need the strict check, with `!== FALSE`, to separate 'not found' case; 'normal' check won't do much.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
function sevens($var) {
    return strpos($var, '7') !== false;
}

$input  = array( /* one million integers */ );
$output = array_map($input, 'sevens');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something always has to loop through the array. But you could look into [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) to reduce your array to only contain numbers ending with "7".

Comment: The question was not ending but containing, this has to be changed a bit.

Comment: It's possible to process an array with `array_walk` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really giving the impression to have done ANY effort for this, but anyway: write a function that echoes an integer if it contains a 7, and call it for each part using `array_map`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a loop in one way or another. You could do a recursive loop, but that is not a good idea at this point.

If you really don't want to do a loop by your self, use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter), [array_walk](http://php.net/array_walk) or [array_map](http://php.net/array_map).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do

```
WHERE intVal LIKE '%7%'
```

and the integer will automatically be cast to a string. It is worth a go, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

@helloThere either you are missing some important input in the question - or you are just not phrasing it correctly: 
there is no algorithm that could "guess" if a number contains the digit 7 - so you'll have to check all the integers one-by-one, hence, this is not a matter of coming up with an "algorithm".

My guess is, that you were asked this question to see if you are familiar with php - expecting  you to come up with the array_map solution or something similar - but even on this case - it's not a matter of "algorithm" - as every solution you'll come up with implements a loop. so the answer is just - not possible!

Comment: you are probably right, I guess they were just testing me to see with what I will come up. Thank you